# Initializing char and string variables in C

Tags: c, initialization, scanf

noob here

I've been doing a lot of research into how to initialize variables in C.  I've concluded that it is good practice to **always** initialize variables.  However, I haven't found a definitive answer as to **how** to initialize variables.  For example, how do you initialize a char and a string?  Sure you could initialize them however you want, but what is a good zero/blank value to use?

```
int a = 0;
char b = ?;
char c[] = ???;
```

Also, what about if you declare and define a variable in a basic program and then use scanf() to get the value from the user?  Should you still initialize the variable before you use scanf()?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A rule of thumb is that in modern programming languages a variable must be declared as close to the point where it is used for the first time, and the initial value of the variable is whatever value it must have when it is used for the first time. In the case of `scanf`, the value of the variable is overwritten. There is no point in initializing it.

Comment: "I've concluded that it is good practice to always initialize variables". That is very debatable. Your `scanf` example is one instance where its arguably pointless to initialise the variable.

Comment: The value of the variable is overwritten by scanf, if successful, **but you also need to remember to check the return value of scanf!** Always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initializing variables with zero/dummy/blank values is a bad practice that should be avoided. Not only it makes no sense, it can prevent modern compiler run-time code sanitization tools from detecting read access to variables that have not been assigned proper values.

In modern C you can declare variables anywhere in the executable code. The greatest benefit of this feature is that almost always you can initialize such variables with *meaningful* values, instead of just zero/dummy/blank values. Take advantage of this. Strive to declare your variables locally, where you are ready to immediately initialize them with meaningful values.

In those rare cases when you have no meaningful value to initialize your variable with, it might be a better idea to leave it uninitialized, instead of initializing it with zero. There are exceptions from this guideline, but they are rare.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if a variable is going to unconditionally have a value assigned to it at some point after it is declared but before it is read, you don't need to initialize it.  You example of the address of a variable being passed to `scanf` () is a good example of a variable that doesn't need to be initialized.

If a variable needs to have some kind of default value, that's when you need to initialize it.  If you find that a variable is read before it is written to, that's a good sign that it needs to be initialized.